# Getting a List of Opened Windows Error

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsarray

I am trying to get a list of opened windows along with their PIDs.

This is the code that I came up with:

CFArrayRef windowList = CGWindowListCreate(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);

```
if (windowList == nil || NULL)
    NSLog(@"The List is null");

for(NSMutableDictionary *entry in (__bridge NSArray *)windowList){
    NSString *ownerName = [entry objectForKey:(__bridge id)kCGWindowOwnerName];
    NSInteger ownerPID = [[entry objectForKey:( __bridge id)kCGWindowOwnerPID]integerValue];
    NSLog(@"%@:%ld",ownerName, ownerPID);
}
```

At the line where I declare ownerName I get an exception (Thread 1: SIGBART)

I can't figure out what's wrong.... the CFArrayRef isn't NULL/nil

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your array all data is not in the form of dictionary. So might be your owner name present array inside array and then inaide dictionary. Si because of that you are getting error